# How to filter results of a query

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgis 2.4 with posgresql 10 in Windows 10.
I have the following SQL query:

```
WITH data (the_geom) as (
  SELECT a.gid,
          CASE WHEN ST_Within(a.geom,b.geom) THEN a.geom 
               ELSE ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom) 
          END AS the_geom  
  FROM source.g100_wby_lakes_r as a 
      JOIN extents.map_areas as b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom,b.geom) 
  WHERE b.map_id='AA01'
) 
INSERT into public.g100_wby_lakes_r (gid,geom) 
select * 
from data 
where st_GeometryType(the_geom)='MULTIPOLYGON';
```

It tries to select the intersection between two multipolygons and only insert into a new table the intersected geometries which are also multipolygons (the intersection could also result in points or lines). All works except for the WHERE clause which gives the following error:

```
ERROR:  column reference "the_geom" is ambiguous
LINE 4: ...id,geom) select * from data where st_GeometryType(the_geom)=...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42702
Character: 351
```

Why is the_geom ambiguous?
How can I change the SQL to make it work?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, @ypercube is spot on and his answer here is great and to the point.

As a side note,

- Use [`ST_CoveredBy` rather than `ST_Within` and check that they don't just `ST_Touches` for completeness](http://postgis.net/2014/03/14/tip_intersection_faster/) (this is a common task)
- CTEs shouldn't be used like this. You're forcing the query to be materialized for no good reason. Consider writing it as an inline table instead `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM ( ... ) AS t`. It'll almost certainly be much faster.
- If you're not indexing `public.g100_wby_lakes_r` consider using a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` which is cleaner.

As a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW public.g100_wby_lakes_r (gid, geom)
  AS
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT a.gid,
        CASE
          WHEN ST_CoveredBy(a.geom,b.geom)
            THEN a.geom
          ELSE ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom) 
        END AS the_geom  
      FROM source.g100_wby_lakes_r as a 
      JOIN extents.map_areas as b
        ON ST_Intersects(a.geom,b.geom)
        AND NOT ST_Touches(a.geom,b.geom)
      WHERE b.map_id='AA01'
    ) AS t(gid, geom)
    WHERE ST_GeometryType(geom)='MULTIPOLYGON';
```

Comment: Thank you  @ypercube for your great answer and Evan for your suggestions. I have made the changes as suggested but I would like to run some more tests including speed tests as the initial results between the two options (a WITH query and an inline INSERTquery) are not consistent. I'll get back here as soon as I have done so.

Comment: @user3716846: Please keep in mind that both inconsistent results and low performance are completely different issues to the ambiguous reference one that you have asked in this thread. So, if you decide that you need help with either of the former, please post a new question. And if the problem with an ambiguous reference is resolved, please [accept the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that's helped you, thanks.

Comment: Thank you @AndriyM for your clarification, but in fairness I think the subject of this thread is How to Filter the results of a query, not about ambiguous references only. Be as it may, I accept that both answers given earlier work now, but I decided to go for the inline INSERT, rather than the WITH option, as I found it more intuitive.
Although I still have a question about my WHERE clause (the crux of filtering), even though it now works, I may make it the subject of another posting.
Thank you all for your great help and advice.

Comment: @user3716846 you're free to mark whatever answer you think addressed the problem you faced. There is no rule or guidance about it, and you're the only authority on chosen-answer. Though, it's better if you mark one so long as you have no more question here or no more work is to be done. And, it's always better to ask more and ask often then to ask for a follow up here: i'm not sure what the question about the where clause remains. You must alias the columns properly or remove the alias and let the names cascade.

Comment: @Evan, I accept your suggestion to use an inline table as the final answer to my question.

Comment: @user3716846: Yes, I understand that you are working on a more or less specific problem, but various issues that you are coming across while solving that problem seem to be specific enough as well. And given that this is a Q&A site and that your question was very specific, an answer addressing and resolving that question should naturally close this thread. It's perfectly all right to ask a new question related to the same problem generally but dealing with a different issue more specifically.

Answer (score 9):

Your CTE:

```
(
  SELECT a.gid,
         ... AS the_geom  
  FROM ...
)
```

produces a table with 2 columns, named `gid` and `the_geom`. But the "wrap" has an obvious glitch, it only has one column:

```
WITH data (the_geom) AS
```

So it says that the table will be named `data` and the first column (re)named to `the_geom`. Now you have 2 columns named `the_geom`! You could have the same effect - but more clear to spot - if you had written:

```
WITH data (the_geom, the_geom) AS
```

The solution is simple. Either remove the column list from that part:

```
WITH data AS
  ( ...
  )
```

or (re)name both columns explicitly:

```
WITH data (gid, the_geom) AS           -- explicit
(
  SELECT a.gid,
         ... AS the_geom  
  FROM ...
) 
INSERT INTO public.g100_wby_lakes_r (gid,geom) 
SELECT gid, the_geom 
FROM data 
WHERE st_GeometryType(the_geom) = 'MULTIPOLYGON' ;
```